# Jenkins sample pipeline job failing every time

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am new learner of Jenkins, I tried to run one very basic sample declarative pipeline code, but every time my job get failed. Any help will be appreciated.

### Sample pipeline code -

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello world!' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Error what I am getting -

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\SamplePipeline\workspace@4
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Stage 1)
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/Memoizer
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepAtomNode.getDescriptor(StepAtomNode.java:61)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepAtomNode.getTypeFunctionName(StepAtomNode.java:81)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode.getDisplayFunctionName(FlowNode.java:194)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.logNodeMessage(WorkflowRun.java:918)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.access$1300(WorkflowRun.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$GraphL.onNewHead(WorkflowRun.java:899)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.notifyListeners(CpsFlowExecution.java:1110)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$3.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:402)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.run(CpsVmExecutorService.java:35)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.Memoizer
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1387)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1342)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1089)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Seems to me like your Jenkins is broken.

Comment: What version of Jenkins do you use?

Comment: My jenkins version is Jenkins 2.235.2 , all other jobs are building successfully except pipeline

Comment: check plugin for pipeline installed correctly